Use the lower of two voltages when one is active
Ok, mostly non electrical guy here.
I have a switch that when closed lights up a 12v lamp. Thats fine.  If a second switch is closed and supplies 6v, I want to use that instead.  But if the first switch is open, the lamp should never light.
It’s like dimming the lamp when the lights are on in my car.  If the switch is closed and the lights are off-12v to the lamp. If the lights are on-6v (or whatever the supply from the lights is dimmed to). If the switch is open-0v.
I thought a simple op amp could do this, or maybe a differential amplifier or two (?). Again, not an analog guy. I tend to scare the smoke out of stuff when I touch it, so I’d appreciate some advice. This is probably a super simple problem but I couldn’t find an analogous scenario to model it from.
I embedded a crude drawing of what I want to do here.

Thanks,
Steve

You could do this easily by connecting a DPST switch (to turn 12V and 6V on or off) to one of the poles of a SPDT switch (to choose between 12V and 6V) but it sounds like you already have switches you have to use? What is this "second switch"? What lamp is being powered? Are we talking a nightlight or a searchlight?

why do you feel that this is an analog problem?  do you need to detect that thr second voltage is less than the first, or is that always true,  is the second voltage source strong enough to light the lamp?

Steve, write something to your answers here. Help others help you.

@vir I'd like the OP to clarify as well, but I wonder if their example is very close to reality: if it's car interior lights the 12V switch (or control circuit) is built in to the car but a dimmer could be added

BTW @Steve, filament lamps at 50% voltage are much less than 50% brightness.  LED 12V lamps run at 6V could give you anything from nothing at all up to full brightness depending on their construction

Sorry for the delay in responding.  Here is the actual scenario.  This is for an MGB that I want to add a light showing me the transmission is in overdrive.  I have 12v from the overdrive switch.  But at night, that 12v light is gonna be really bright.  So I'd like to have the light follow the dimmer switch when it's active.  This is a 50 year old car and is 'analog'.  I have a dimmer for the lights, so say that's 8v.  When the overdrive is active I want to use the 8v source when the lights are on and the 12v source when the lights are off.  I want the light off when the o/d is off.

The dimmer is for the instrument cluster lights, and I have LED lights on those already and the brightness is fine.  I want this new light to match those when the lights are on (because it's dark out), but be full brightness when off (since it's daytime).
I appreciate all the suggestions to date!  I hope the explanation above makes it clearer what I am trying to do.

The following circuit relies on the fact that 12 volts minus 6 volts is 6 volts: -

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
As shown above, the lamp is unlit but illuminates with the full 12 volts when SW1 closes. The illumination diminishes when SW2 changes state. No relays harmed.

The following solution draws current from the 6 volt source (may be more preferable) and, uses only one relay: -

simulate this circuit
So, if the 6 volts is present and, SW1 is pressed, the lamp is powered from 6 volts. If only 12 volts is present and SW1 is pressed then the lamp receives 12 volts. D1 is shown if required.
If SW1 isn't pressed then the lamp is off.

This will work only if the 6 V source can sink current.

I don't think that's a big deal but, nevertheless, this can be achieved with a single relay @Transistor

The OP has clarified in comments that the 6V source is in fact a variable voltage from a dimmable instrument cluster.

Andy, can you describe how that would work?  I shamelessly admit I'm seeking an answer I can just implement, but I learn from those answers too...

There are two circuits in my answer. Do you understand the first one? Do you know what an electromagnetic relay does and how it works?

Andy, you mentioned one relay and a transistor. I know how relays work. But I’m not much of an electrical guy. Take pity on me. :). I follow the second circuit and that does appear to do what I want.

Hmm, but 12v is only present if SW1 is closed.

@SteveStrublic @transistor is a user on stack exchange. What do you need explaining?

Ah, thanks.  Brain fart on that one!

@SteveStrublic so are you OK on how it works now?

I think so.  Thank you!

@SteveStrublic then you have a choice to make... please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question.

Here's a relay circuit that might do what you want.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Just for form's sake - and to head off a discussion later - I would add diodes in across the coils.

@vir or relays with built-in diodes.  12V automotive relays like that are common, not sure about 6V option

yeah 6V is a propblem for automotive relays (especially as it's variable) - but can use the park light circuit instead to drive the relay

it can be further simplifies if the overdrive switch can be a switch to ground,  but I'm guessing the 12V is the overdrive solenoid circuit so that's not an option.

That's a nice update, and the "park lights" signal can almost certainly be taken from the input to the dimmer module to avoid having to run single wires to different places.  Then you can also use handily packaged relays with spade terminals and built-in diodes, as both the coils run at 12V

...annoyingly, while 6V automotive relays exist (mainly for old motorbikes), the ones I can find aren't specified as having built-in diodes - which do make for much simpler assembly in car mod applications

Yeah, the switch supplies 12v to a solenoid, that engages to drive an oil pump that hydraulically engages a planetary cluster to change the final drive ratio.  Ground would be easier - even I think I could figure that out :)
